# Get access to native iOS Twitter / Facebook credentials through Cordova webview

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, twitter

I've searched everywhere but can't figure out what plugins (is any) are available for accessing the native iOS/Twitter credentials.

How can I get access to the existing system accounts instead of using a InAppBrowser that forces the user to enter their credentials again?

Is there any way to do this within a webview?